# Object reference error even when object is not null

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

i have an application wherein i have incorporate a "Remember Me" feature for the login screen.
I do this by creating a cookie when the user logs in for the first time, so next time when the user visits the site i get the cookie and load the user information.

i have written the code for loading user information in a common class in the App_Code folder...and all my pages inherit from this class.

code for loading the user info is as follows:

```
public static void LoadUserDetails(string emailId)
{
    UsersEnt currentUser = UsersBL.LoadUserInfo(emailId);

    if (currentUser != null)
        HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUser"] = currentUser;
}
```

Now the problem is i get an "Object reference" error when i try to store the currentUser  object in the session variable (even though the currentUser object is not null). However the password property in the currentUser object is null.

Am i getting the error because of this...or is there some other reason??

thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming it's the final line which is causing the problem, that suggests that either `HttpContext.Current` or `HttpContext.Current.Session` is null. I suggest you find out which it is, and then work out why.

Answer (score 2):

HttpContext.Current.Session is probably null.

Code that uses the State has to be placed after the AcquireRequestState Event has called. See the [page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wt3wttw(vs.71).aspx) for more information.

Try putting your code after or inside the Page_Load method.

Answer (score 0):

If it is throwing the exception on the line:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUser"] = currentUser;
```

Then the only other explanation is that HttpContext.Current.Session is null.